# Set the flag if a column values are matching with those in another vector

Tags: r

Suppose I've a `data.frame` as follows:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,54,3,5,6,87,6))
```

And I have a vector `temp` as follows:

```
temp<-c(1,3,5,9)
```

Now, I want to create a new column `flag` on to my data.frame, where it should be `1` where `id` is in `temp` and `0` elsewhere. This is what I tried:

```
a$flag <- ifelse(a$id==temp, 1, 0)
```

and desired output should be `(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)`.

But from my code above, `flag` is not getting updated properly. What am I missing here?
Can/should I use `%in%`? If so, how?

Thank you for any help

Comment: +1, welcome to SO. However, this seems to be a pretty basic question. I suggest you search SO before posting.

Comment: `ifelse` didn't work because of recycling due to different lengths of your vectors.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you're looking for. There are a couple of problems in how you're making your `data.frame`:

```
a <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,54,3,5,6,87,6),
                flag = 0)
```

Then to update values of `flag` to 1 where `id` is in `temp`, you can index those values using `[` and the logical test `%in%`, and assign them 1

```
a$flag[a$id %in% temp] <- 1

a
#    id flag
# 1   1    1
# 2   3    1
# 3   4    0
# 4   5    1
# 5   7    0
# 6   8    0
# 7   9    1
# 8   6    0
# 9  54    0
# 10  3    1
# 11  5    1
# 12  6    0
# 13 87    0
# 14  6    0
```

Comment: Perfecto ! I dont know why ifelse didnt work though. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @carlwhyte, try running `a$id == temp` and try to understand what has happened (including the warning message). Hint: since `temp` is not of the same length as `a$id`, it gets *recycled*.

Comment: Or alternatively `a$flag <- as.numeric(a$id %in% temp)` which will save the need for pre-assigning `a$flag`

Comment: Another option: `within(a, flag <- as.numeric(id %in% temp))`

Comment: `as.numeric` to give the OP his expected output. But personally, I would drop it and just store `TRUE/FALSE` for a "flag". It also uses less memory.

Comment: @flodel - I tend to prefer `0/1` output so if the data ends up in a `csv` output format it is simpler to deal with in external programs.

Answer (score 1):

```
a$flag <- 0 + (a$id %in% temp )
```

The the only reason that `ifelse` failed, was the use of "==" when the logical test should have been `%in%`.

```
 a<- data.frame(id=c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,6,54,3,5,6,87,6))
temp<-c(1,3,5,9)

a$flag <- ifelse(a$id %in% temp, 1, 0)

> a
   id flag
1   1    1
2   3    1
3   4    0
4   5    1
5   7    0
6   8    0
7   9    1
8   6    0
9  54    0
10  3    1
11  5    1
12  6    0
13 87    0
14  6    0
```

I prefer demonstrating non-`ifelse` solutions because I find that construct generalizes poorly to mode complex situations.

Comment: why an implicit conversion? People have suggested `as.numeric`.

Comment: Valid criticism. The code underlying the "+" operation will do the coercion. It's fewer keystrokes, but probably not faster, since there will be an additional vector created and the calculation. I think it might be helpful to understand R implicit type conversions.